# Pass returned value from a method in a service to another method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that connects to 2 different API endpoints, this one gets the user's id and a JWT token:

```
@Injectable()
 export class UserService {

  appLogin = 'http://url.for.the.login.api';
  //returns id and token
  userData = 'http://url.for.the.user_info.api';
  //returns user info

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.appLogin}`);
    //gets id and token, can display values in the template like this {{currentUser.id}}
  }

 }
```

Then I need that another method uses the id and the token returned to use those values to make another `GET`request, like this:
`http://url.for.the.user_info.api/userID?token=token_string`

I have this:

```
 getInfo(id: number, token: string) {

    let userData = this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.appLogin}` + id + '?token=' + token);
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${userData}`);
}
```

But I'm lost with this, thank you for your help.

Comment: What version of `rxjs` are you using? Also, what is `userData`, because the `get` function is expecting a URL

Comment: This: rxjs@^6.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `switchMap` function, like so:

```
return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.appLogin}` + id + '?token=' + token)
    .pipe(switchMap(userData) => this.http.get<User[]>(`${userData}`))
```

You may need to add the following import statement for `switchMap`:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

By piping the original request through `switchMap`, we can create a new `Observable`